# Create evenly spaced out sequence in SQL

Tags: sql

So this should be fairly simple, and I'm sure there's an embarrassingly easily solution I'm missing, but here goes:

I want to create a grid of numbers based on two numeric variables.

More specifically, I want to select the 5th and 95th percentile of each variable, then cut up the difference between those two values into 100 parts, and then group by those.

So basically what I need is in pseudocode

```
(5th percentile)+(95th percentile-5th percentile)/100*[all numbers from 0 to 100]
```

I can pick out the 5th and 95th percentile with the following query:

```
SELECT Min(subq.lat) as latitude, percentile FROM
(SELECT round(latitude,2) as lat, ntile(100) OVER (order by latitude desc) as    
'percentile' FROM table   ORDER BY latitude DESC) AS subq
where percentile in (5,95)
group by 2
```

And I can can create a list of numbers from 0 to 100 as well.

But how to combine those two is something that's a little beyond me.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So basically you want to create a smooth line going from the 5th %ile value to the 95th, having 100 steps between them? Is it possible that you really want 90 steps (so that each step could represent a %ile point)?

Comment: No, it's definitely 100. Basically, 5 to 95 is a confidence interval which I want to segment into 100 parts. Otherwise I could just take the where clause out of my sql above and be done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I follow what you're after, but it could be as simple as looping through 1-100, performing your calculation for each set and inserting them into a results table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Results (Counter_ INT, Calc_Value FLOAT)
GO
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=100)
BEGIN

--Do Stuff
INSERT INTO #Results
SELECT Counter_ = @intFlag
,Calc_Value = (calculation logic)/@intFlag

SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
GO
```

The 'Do Stuff' portion gets executed for each value 1 - 100, the (Calculation logic) would obviously need to be replaced with whatever logic you use.  If those values are constant for 1-100, you could set them as variables so they don't have to run 100 times. Roughly:

```
CREATE TABLE #Results (Counter_ INT, Calc_Value FLOAT)
GO
DECLARE @intFlag INT, @Percentile_Value FLOAT = (Calculation Logic)
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=100)
BEGIN

--Do Stuff
INSERT INTO #Results
SELECT Counter_ = @intFlag
,Calc_Value = @Percentile_Value/@intFlag

SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want to do with window functions.  Basically, do the percentile calculation with `row_number()` and the total count.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT lat,
       ((seqnum - 0.05 * cnt) / (0.95 * cnt - 0.05 * cnt)) * 100 as NewPercentile
FROM (SELECT round(latitude,2) as lat,
             row_number() over (order by latitude) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      FROM table
      ORDER BY latitude DESC
     ) AS subq
where seqnum between 0.05 * cnt and 0.95 * cnt
```